# How to add required .net to InstallShield12

Tags: .net, installation, installshield

I created a app with VS2012 with version 4.5.

I want to created a setup file, I use InstallSheild12 for this.

In application File step, i add all file of debug folder.

When i Build Installation, Get error

`ISDEV : warning -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework.  It is recommended that the release include the .NET Framework.`

Which step can i add required file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean InstallShield 12, not InstallShield 2012 (yeah it's a bit of a name clash), your best bet is to create or find a prerequisite that installs .NET Framework version 4.5. Unfortunately since it's not built-in, the build won't know that it's .NET, and the warning won't necessarily go away.

(Actually the same advice goes for InstallShield 2012, but that version might include such a prerequisite already; InstallShield 12 is definitely too old for that.)

Comment: won't the error still persist?  I believe the error will persist even if a prq is added.  the error indicates athat .net hasn't been configured for that release configuration.  My IS2012 spring premier includes .net 2.  This is rather annoying is it makes it impossible to turn on warnings as errors.